# Setting all pixels with value <= 0 to "nodata" in DEM raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS.

I have a DEM raster with pixel values between about 3000 and -0.0003.
I need to set all pixel with a value of 0 **and smaler** (<=0) to "nodata" (for later raster calculations and to reduce the filesize).

It seems for me that this is a task for the raster calculator (set value of  pixels <=0 to "nodata") or a reclassification (set value of  pixels <=0 to "nodata" and keep all other values) but I dont know how.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I didn't find a one-tool solution, but you can first use raster calculator to turn all values below a certain threshold to zero and then use gdal_translate with -a_nodata 0 to turn the 0 into nodata.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 57):

It can be done in one step in QGIS in the raster calculator.

In QGIS3, for a raster layer named "x", use the following expression:

```
(("x">0)*"x") / (("x">0)*1 + ("x"<=0)*0)
```

This trick maps raster values x>0 into the ratio x/1 = x, and raster values x<=0 into the ratio 0/0 = NaN. This NaN is rendered as FLOAT_MIN (aka -3.402832...e+38) if the raster is 4-byte float.

Strangely this question seems to have been around a while, with (as far as my quick Google search today shows) most respondents saying it can't be done in a single step. It certainly shouldn't need to be hacked like this. The QGIS documentation could be better too.

Answer (score 23):

You can also save the layer (right click, save as ...) and specify a nodata range. This will keep the original nodata and create new nodatas for the specified range of values.

Answer (score 19):

Here's the GRASS mapcalc expressions to set a range to NULL:

```
r.mapcalc "dem_corrected = if(dem<=0, null(), dem)"
```

Answer (score 10):

Many thanks to Dominik.  My first answer is not correct for QGIS 2.8.3 (the expression `"myraster@1" > 0` returns 0 or 1 for non-*nodata* input, for *nodata* input it returns *nodata*).

<del>The following QGIS *Raster Calculator* expression should be sufficient
(raster layer named "myraster"), since the QGIS *Raster Calculator*
sets all pixels that do not satisfy the condition to *nodata*:</del>

```
("myraster@1" > 0) * "myraster@1"
```

The following solution is based on https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/no_data.html, and works for QGIS 2.8.3 with SAGA 2.1.2.

In QGIS Processing, use the SAGA *Raster calculator* and enter the following in *Formula*:

```
ifelse(g1=0, 0/0, ifelse(g1<0, 0/0, g1))
```

or

```
ifelse(a=0, 0/0, ifelse(a<0, 0/0, a))
```

This will turn all values less than or equal to 0 into nodata (0/0).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, but had *BOTH* values I wanted to convert to no-data *AND* existing no-data values in the raster.

[image: Identify Results]

I came to this page for help, but I think there is a caveat to the approaches here. The methods of @underdark and @Micha only seem to work where there are no existing no-data values in the raster.

To get round this, you need to convert both the no-data values, and the values you wish to convert to no-data, to a consistent number. It is then okay to use the second step of @underdark.

To do this, use the Processing Toolbox > Reclassify Grid Values (SAGA) to convert the values and the no-data values to a common number (e.g. -999), at the same time. Specifically, use method "range" and specify the range. Then in replace no-data values, choose this same value (e.g. -999). Untick replace other values. This works for a single value change or more complex changes too.

Then follow the method of @underdark, and save the raster using Raster>Conversion>Translate, and tick no-data, entering the value you used (e.g. -999).

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible in GDAL raster calculator and (imho) more intuitive than native raster calculator. Since it uses numpy functions, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`numpy.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan) like so:

```py
where(A<=0,nan,A)
```

if you have loaded you layer as "Input layer A"

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a solution to this problem in QGIS. However, exporting the raster to R was easy:

```
library(raster)

dem<-raster('/home/.../DEM.tif')
values(dem)[values(dem) <= 0] = NA
writeRaster(dem,'/home/.../DEM_0.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```