# Convert 0's to NoData in QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis-2, raster-calculator

What is the easiest way to convert cells with a value of 0 to NoData in QGIS Raster Calculator?

Comment: Yep didn't see this one, that answer works, but would be nice to be able to do it in raster calc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with the raster calculator, but according to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/how-to-set-all-pixels-with-value-0-to-nodata-in-dem-raster), you can use GDAL's translate function (Raster > Conversion > Translate) to convert 0's to NoData (check the "No data" box and let the corresponding value to 0).

Comment: Yep this works, my bad didn't see that existing question, cheers.

Comment: Although seems odd there isn't an equivalent to arcmap raster calculator 'SetToNull', would be nice functionality