# How to perform IDW interpolation on ocean data points without interpolating on land?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I am using QGIS 2.14 Essen. I am working on ocean data points and I would like to interpolate them to create a raster. The problem is, when I do the interpolation, the areas where there is land are also filled with data. What I want to do is to interpolate the data only on the oceans area and not on land. I want the land areas to remain with no data.

Is there anyway to this?

Comment: Why not rasterise your land polygons?  Then, with conditional calculations, wherever your interpolated raster overlaps a land pixel, set it to no data.

Comment: I am very new to GIS so this is very helpful. Thank you. Maybe you could put it as an answer, so I could accept it as a useful answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is to rasterise your land polygons and perform a conditional calculation so that the land pixels are set to No Data.

1. Convert Vector to Raster

   [image]

   Your input file name is your land polygon file.
   [image]
2. Use conditional statements in raster calculator to convert the land raster to null values and all other pixels will be your interpolated raster.  I don't use QGIS often enough to know the exact workflow for this.  But there are plenty of posts on this site to get you started.  Like **[this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/81640/7424)**. Or alternatively you can use a mask which is described on the page for the [raster calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator).  You'd mask out your land pixels.