# Working with NaN/null and different extents in QGIS Raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, null

When it comes to NULL value and different extents of rasters I find it extremely cumbersome to use QGIS raster calculator. As far as I am aware there is no way to operate with NaN/Null value. So no matter what you do NaN/NULL in any input become NULL in output.

As far as I am aware you can't do anything like:

(raster1 is NULL)*raster2+(raster1 is not NULL)*raster1

I have similar issue with extents of raster. I have one raster of large extent and second covering only small part of it. I need to update null/zero values of large extent raster to values in small extent raster. If I do calculation below everything off of small extent becomes NULL/Nan.

(largeraster = 0)*smallraster + (largeraster != 0)*largeraster

**Is there any way to be able to operate with NULL value in raster calculator? Is there any way to not trash all values in areas where all rasters do not overlap?**

Comment: i think SAGA allows this using **0/0** to represent NaN, e.g. [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129629/55203)

Comment: As to your second question, to replace nodata cells by the values in small extent raster, SAGA `Patching` tool (in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster Tools`) is powerful and reliable.

Comment: StevenKay and Kazuhito thank you for your tips, will give it a try

Comment: I have just perform it with r.patch from the Processing Toolbox. Not an obviuos way to control the right parameters, but I will post a solution once I master it

Comment: @Marco nice revival. I do wonder if this is still problem in QGIS 3.14 as I don't process rasters in QGIS anymore. At that time I ended up writing python script. Also temporarily was using model builder, to change null values to normal values and back. And resizing, copying rasters, burning values from rasters converted to xyz points and other fun stuff as workarounds.

Comment: My scripting tools are too limited, otherwise I would ask for your python code. GRASS is very powerful for raster manipulation, but it is not friendly at all. QGIS does it quite well at making easier to work with tools from GRASS. I think it is still a problem, I have an almost duplicated question about no-data values https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357723/dealing-with-no-data-values-in-raster-calculator-of-qgis

Answer (score 2):

Looking back, your question(s) seems to be about how we fill the void of large raster by a small raster. (I had been thinking two equations in your question were independent).

Using Raster calculator, I think I would suggest a workflow like below:

1. Change NULL (NoData) of the large raster to 0 (zero).
2. Merge two rasters (replace zeros of large raster by values from small raster)

---

(1) Change Null to 0

- A useful tool is SAGA `Reclassify values` (`QGIS Processing Toolbox |
  SAGA | Raster tools | Reclassify values`).

  We use only `replace no data values` option. Keep this ticked-on, and
  set `new value for no data values` to `0.0` (I think this is default
  value).

  Make sure `replace other values` option is off.

  When <kbd>Run</kbd> this tool, the NoData cells become `0`.

(2) Merge two rasters, only filling voids of large raster

1. Start Raster calculator
2. Highlight Large raster on the list and click on <kbd>Current Layer extent</kbd>. This will ensure extent of your output.
3. equation: `("Large@1" != 0) * "Large@1" + ("Large@1" = 0) * "Small@1"`