# Dealing with no-data values in raster calculator of QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, nodata

I am trying to patch two rasters with raster calculator but I am not finding the way to work with no-data values.

- Lager@1 has some information I need as first option, this has as no-data -9999 (reading in the properties)
- Lager@2 has the information I want to complete what is nodata in Lager@1

This command does not produce values where Lager@1 is no-data

`("Large@1" != -9999) * "Large@1" + ("Large@1" = -9999) * "Lager@2"`

I would like to avoid or skip the reclasification becase I might have many zeros and I need to perform this with diferrent rasters that might have different no-data formats, for instance Lager@2 has -99999 instead of -9999.

In GRASS this would be an `r.patch` task, but I cannot (or I do not know how to) control the order in the r.patch available in the Processing Toolbox.

`r.patch input= Lager@1, Lager@2 output=Lager@3`

[image: Result of patching of two raster maps containing NULLs using the default settings]

Comment: I checked the history of the toolbox and I found the command with r.patch and then I copied and edited for my needs (order of raster files) and pasted the `processing.run("grass7:r.patch", {'input':...` in the console. It worked, but it was not so frinedly as I would love QGIS to be

Comment: Use Fill NoData cells (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#fill-nodata-cells), also possible in batch mode and change `nodata` values to `0`. I don't know of a direct way, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/420195/88814

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `r.patch`, or using `isnull()` in `r.mapcalc.simple`, or using `&&&` or `|||` operators.

Comment: Hi, is ´r.mapcalc` behind the QGIS Calculator? I did not find that information and it would open a door for all its functions and documentation, which is an essential part of a tool. Please confirm my understanding of "r.mapcalc (the QGIS calculator)"

Comment: Sorry - I was incorrect. You're right, `r.mapcalc` is not the backend to the QGIS calculator. I've updated the suggestion. You can use `r.mapcalc.simple` instead of the QGIS calculator.