# QGIS raster calculator syntax to turn `nodata` values to other values

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, nodata, null

In QGIS raster calculator, how is the syntax to refer to `nodata` values? Lets say I have a raster and want to generate a binary output raster with `data -> 1` and `nodata -> 0`. There is an easy way to achieve this using the tool `Fill NoData cells` ([see docu](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#fill-nodata-cells)), but I'm wondering how to do it directly in raster calulator.

I tried different syntaxes like:

- `"Raster@1" >=0`
- `"Raster@1" / "Raster@1"`
- `"Raster@1" = -9999` (where -9999 is assigned to `nodata` values)

Output is always `1 / -3.40...e+38` (the last one the default for `nodata` values). `nodata` always remains `nodata`, no matter what I try.

How is it possible to convert `nodata` values to a specific value? So basically I look for what is [described here for ArcGIS](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010059).

Comment: What value is used as nodata in your source raster?

Comment: @user30184 - `nodata` is `-9999` - but using this value does not help, see updated question.