# No Data Analysis In QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have two rasters and am using QGIS 3.6

I want to know which areas in raster 1 that are "no data" are not "no data" in raster 2.

I also want to know what areas in raster 2 that are "no data" are not "no data" in raster 1.

I assume that the QGIS raster calculator is the tool to use. I dont think there is a way to use conditional statements and I am unsure how to enter No data into it.

Comment: Isnt that guide outdated. None of those no data formulas work in the latest raster calculator.

Comment: Spelling NoData as "no data" is confusing, and indicates you do not understand the concept of null values.

Comment: The GRASS functions will work > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/how-to-set-all-pixels-with-value-0-to-nodata-in-dem-raster

Comment: Thank you for your correction Vince. I was using the "Reclassify by Table" tool which refers to null values as "no data".