# How to transfer NaNs from raster to other having different dimensions?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, gdal

I have one high resolution raster `1m` with dimensions `12671x12756` and other a Sentinel 2A raster with dimensions `1606x1596`. Both of them are of same extent but the high-res tiles has some `nans` and I want to transfer them to the low res tile, basically, make the same areas `0s` as well.

I tried using `numpy` but there are lot of dimensions mismatch errors, what else can I try here?

Comment: Does the nans have some value which can be selected using raster calculator? Maybe somthing like this is possible: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/how-to-set-all-pixels-with-value-0-to-nodata-in-dem-raster But set the nans as your 1m raster instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resample your high resolution 1m raster to match the resolution of the lower resolution tile.
That should eliminate the dimension mismatch errors and allow the NaN data to be transferred to the lower resolution image.