# Vegetation removal from DEM before or after contour line extraction

Tags: qgis-3, dem, blendergis

I have a DEM from a terrassed olive grove (single trees apart from each other) and would like to get clean contour lines (without trees / bushes) from it using QGIS3.

Cleaning up all the contour lines manually seems daunting, so I hope there is a more automated process within QGIS3 or even before extracting contour lines...

What would be a sensible workflow starting with the DEM? Or do I need another software like Blender to "erase" the trees before extracting the contour lines in QGIS?

[image: after contour line extraction in QGIS3]

[image: DEM]

Comment: Did you create the DSM yourself from lidar data?

Comment: This looks like a LiDAR first return dataset.  Go to the data source and get the bare-earth surface model (DTM?) and generate the contours from that surface.

Comment: No lidar data. The DSM was created by mapsmadeeasy.com. I've uploaded the drone images there and received a georeferenced Tif and other files like .mtl .obj .las .kmz and different .jpgs
Sorry, complete beginner here. I'd need a concrete advice how to get a DTM and with what kind of software (ideally QGIS or blender) this can be achieved.

Comment: Create a polygon layer. Digitize the parts you want to keep and the ones you dont. Add a field with value -1 and 1. Convert to raster. Use raster calculator with if else to [set the parts you dont want to keep to null](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/how-to-set-all-pixels-with-value-0-to-nodata-in-dem-raster). Fill no data to fill the gaps. But the best would of course be to recreate the DEM from the point cloud.

Comment: Thanks @BERA, could you specify further especially what software you're referring to? Can this all be done in QGIS?

Again, total newbie here :) thx for patience

Answer (score 1):

Create areas of nodata where there are areas you want to remove then fill in the nodata:

1. Create a polygon layer and digitize the features you want to remove
   [image]
2. Rasterize the polygon layer with "A fixed value to burn" = 1
3. Use Raster Calculator to set the values where there are polygons (value 1) to 0, and
   the other parts to the DEM values:

`("Rasterized@1" = 1)*0 + ("Rasterized@1"=0)*"DSM@1"`

[image]

4. With gdal translate set the zero's to nodata:
   [image]
5. Use Fill nodata to fill in the holes:
   [image]

(This is also a method for calculating the volume of things in a DEM. Take the original DEM - filled DEM. Which is what I use it for)

Comment: Thank you @BERA. Your explanation seems very helpful! I'm going to try it out asap!

Comment: So i've tried your suggested workflow and got stuck at step 2 (Rasterize polygon layer with a fixed value to burn = 1) but all I ever get is a new layer "OUTPUT" with a min. value = 1.79769e+308 and max. value = -1.79769e+308 (and not min. 0 and max. 1)

After having tried all the possible combinations (mostly errors in width / height) I've input the value = 1 for all the height / width / output extent (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) and the above value is what i get.

Could you pls point me to the correct parameters for rasterize?