# Obtain coordinates with specific NDVI value using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I made new layer for NDVI.  Now, I have to get coordinates for some range of NDVI.

Let's say I have to get coordinates for NDVI from 0.1 to 0.3. How I can do it?
I saw several YouTube tutorials - but there was nothing about NDVI coordinates.

Should I create new layer for coordinates or some grid?

Comment: Set everything above 0.3 as transparent in your symbology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question entails two steps:

1. filter/mask the NDVI for pixels within required range.
2. get pixel coordinates.

For step 1, run a raster calculator expression like so

```
(("ndvi">= 0.1 AND "ndvi" <=0.3 )*"ndvi") / (("ndvi">= 0.1 AND "ndvi" <=0.3)*1 + ("x""ndvi"< 0.1 OR "ndvi" > 0.3)*0)
```

The result being a raster that retains the ndvi value for pixels within required range.
[method described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/how-to-set-all-pixels-with-value-0-to-nodata-in-dem-raster)

For step 2, use you can use the `Raster pixels to points` tool, to sample each pixel center.